# Python script for AWS to gather information about all instances in the current region. It should group them by AMI's and how many instances use them

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Python script for AWS  to gather information about all instances in the current region. It should group them by AMI's and how many instances use them. My question is....I can get this script to pull 1 of the my 4 instances from my account with exactly all the information i need in dictionary format. but i cannot get it to list all the AMI's ....How would i get it to pull the rest that are running?

enter code here
import boto3
import pprint

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name ='kenjiro310', region_name='us-east-2')
# Let's use Amazon EC2
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name="us-east-2")

response = ec2_client.describe_images(Owners=['self'])
pprint.pprint(response)
```

Comment: Ok. What is your question?

Comment: My question is....I can get this script to pull 1 of the my 4 instances from my account with exactly all the information i need  in dictionary format. but i cannot get it to list all the AMI's ....How would i get it to pull the rest that are running?

Answer (score 2):

Probably using ec2 resource is more convenient:

```
import boto3

ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')
ec2_instances = ec2_resource.instances.filter(Filters=[{
    'Name': 'instance-state-name',
    'Values': ['running']
}])
instances = []
for ec2_instance in ec2_instances:
    instances.append({
        "ami": ec2_instance.image_id,
        "id": ec2_instance.id, 
        "public_ip": ec2_instance.public_ip_address

    })
print(instances)
```

These are the available [attributes](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#instance).